# How to left align key text in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

[image]

By default, gnuplot aligns keys on right. Since I'm putting the legend on the top right section, I'd like to align them on left.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `Left` keyword to the `set key` command:

```
set key Left
```

Type `? key` at the gnuplot command line for more details on messing with the key.

Comment: It aligned the  text, but not the labels (color boxes). So, it's now looking weird, the text is aligned on the left, but the label boxes are on their right. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @narengi make sure you write "Left" (key sensitive) = left text alignment and not "left" = put the box in the left side

Comment: @narengi: I also stumbled over this issue, using `Left`did not help. The only way I found was to use something like `set key at graph 0.65,0.975`, but than the alignment is lost.

Comment: nope, the right command is  `set key left`

Answer (score 3):

For aligning the labels as well:

```
set key reverse Left
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: From ```? key```: ,,The text and sample can be reversed (`reverse`)". While this is neat, otherwise the answer does not seem to bring more than that of @andyras.

Answer (score 0):

Since both other answers did not work for me, I am writing the option that worked

```
set key top left Left reverse
```